# Weil restriction of a base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, extension-field, elliptic-curves, algebraic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}$

Let $G$ be an algebraic group over $K$ and let $L/K$ be a finite separable extension. Consider the Weil restriction $G' := \Res^L_K(G \times_K L)$ of the base change $G \times_K L$.

> Is it true that $G'$ is isomorphic to $G$ as algebraic groups over $K$? Is it at least true if $G$ is an elliptic curve (1-dimensional projective algebraic group)? If not, what is the relation between $G$ and $G'$?

I believe that $G' \times_K L$ is isomorphic to $G^{[L:K]}$ (at least if $L/K$ is Galois). But I am not sure.

Comment: In fact, see the theorem in "Galois descent and twists of an Abelian variety." p. 53 (http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa73/aa7314.pdf): for instance if $G$ is an elliptic curve and $L/K$ is quadratic then Res^L_K(E) = E times E' where E' is the quadratic twist of E (found in prop 6 of "The Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture for an elliptic curve over Q(sqrt[4]{5})")

Comment: In the above, "Res^L_K(E) = E times E'" should read "Res^L_K(E) isisogenous to E times E'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they need not be isomorphic as schemes.

It might be helpful to see an example. Let $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ be an extension of fields.

Consider, some algebraic group over $\mathbb{R}$. I will take the multiplicative group $G=\text{Spec}\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(xy-1)$ as an example and its base change is $G\times_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}=\text{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy-1)$ If I want to look at the Weil restriction to $\mathbb{R}$, this becomes, $G'=\mathbb{R}[x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2]/(x_1y_1-x_2y_2-1, x_2y_1-x_1y_2)$.

How did I get these relations? Basically, we are saying that $\Re(xy-1)=0$ and $\Im (xy-1)=0$ and we wrote $x=x_1+ix_2$ and $y=y_1+iy_2$.

I am not sure what meaningful things we can say apart from the obvious statements. i.e. Look at the functor of points, $G'(K)=(G\times_K L)(L)$.

Comment: Yes, I am stupid.   Res^C_R( G_{m, C} ) is not isomorphic to G_{m, R} ... (the real points of the first one are C^times, while it is R^times for the second one)